# Call subclass's overriding function from base class in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have a class, called *Screen*:

```
public class Screen extends GameObject
{
    //GameObject is a class extending Sprite and implemented by just some variables and methods 

    public static var scrStage:Stage;

    public function Screen(argStage:Stage) {
        scrStage = argStage;
        initObjects();
    }

    private function initObjects():void {
        // empty method
    }

}
```

And a class called *PlayScreen*:

```
public class PlayScreen extends Screen
{
    //declares TextFields and GameObjects

    public function PlayScreen(argStage:Stage) {
        super(argStage);
        //addChild those TextFields and GameObjects
    }

    private function initObjects():void {
        // initializes those TextFields and GameObjects
    }

}
```

}

When the constructor of *PlayScreen* is called, *Screen*'s constructor is called too. Inside it, *scrStage* is assigned to *argStage*, *initObjects*() is called. *PlayScreen*(subclass)'s *initObjects*() is supposed to be called but *Screen*(base class)'s *initObjects*() is called instead.

So would you mind helping me callling the PlayScreen's initObjects() when the constructor of PlayScreen is called? Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

Oops.
After debugging somewhere else in my project, I have found the solution to this:

```
//edit in Screen class
private function initObjects():void {}
//to
protected function initObjects():void {}
//or public

//and in PlayScreen class
private function initObjects():void {}
//to
protected override function initObjects():void {}
//or public
```

Comment: initObjects() is a private method and so is not inherited. There's no reason for the PlayScreen version to be called when the superclass version is called. The fact that you did not have to override it should have given you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just not call `initObjects` under Screen since it's an empty method anyway, and call it from your `PlayScreen` as such:

```
public class Screen extends GameObject
{
    //GameObject is a class extending Sprite and implemented by just some variables and methods 

    public static var scrStage:Stage;

    public function Screen(argStage:Stage) {
        scrStage = argStage;
    }
}

public class PlayScreen extends Screen
{
    //declares TextFields and GameObjects

    public function PlayScreen(argStage:Stage) {
        super(argStage);
        //addChild those TextFields and GameObjects
        initObjects();
    }

    private function initObjects():void {
        // initializes those TextFields and GameObjects
    }

}
```

Comment: I disagree. That's an alternative way. I wrote that. But I just don't want to write it in every other class extending Screen class. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: would your initObjects logic not change in each extension of Screen?  If they would not change, then why not just implement on the Screen level, if they are changing on a per extension basis however, I wouldn't see a way around it aside from providing an implementation under each extended version of the class